# Vue.draggable lazy loading?

Tags: vue.js, lazyloading, draggable

Есть draggable листы на ~900 элементов. Из-за того что страница при перетаскивании карточки каждый раз перестраивается есть ощутимая задержка. Можно ли как то скрестить друг с другом draggable и v-lazy, или как то иначе рендерить лишь видимую на экране часть карточек элементов?

```
<draggable @end="change" :animation="200" ghost-class="ghost-card" group="elements">
            <element-card v-for="element in elements" @lock="lock" @move="move" :key="element.id" :title="title" class="mt-3 cursor-move"></element-card>
        </draggable>
```